# Repeating same test cases as part of my test

Tags: java, selenium, testng

I have a test (which I developed using java selenium testng) which contains several tests cases and I want to be able to repeat them 'X' times.

I have written the test that would meet what I want to achieve if I would launch this test with no repetitions.

```
@Test(priority = 110, dataProvider = "backupDetailsProvider")
public void addBackupByDevice(String... devices) throws ApiException {
    BackupRow backupRow = backupPage.addNewBackupByDevices(devices);
    backupNameDevice = backupRow.backupNameTxt;
    Assert.assertNotNull(backupRow, "failed to add backup=[first] to server");
    info("user=[%s] added successfully" , backupRow);
    addToBackupMap(backupNameDevice);
}

@DataProvider(name = "backupFileProvider")
public Object[][] backupFileProvider(){
    return initSingleParamProvider(backupFileResponseNonLabled);
}

@DataProvider(name = "backupDetailsProvider")
public Object[][] backupDetailsProvider() {
    return new Object[][]{
            {new String[]{nonLabelDevice.vendor + "-" + nonLabelDevice.ip}}
    };
}

@Test(priority = 130, dataProvider = "backupScheduleProvider", groups = {BACKUP_COMPLETE})
public void verifyInLogBackupJobStarted(ScheduleRequest schedule) throws Exception {
    servicesLog.waitAndVerifyBackupJobStarted(schedule);
}

@DataProvider(name = "backupScheduleProvider")
public Object[][] backupScheduleProvider() {
    return initParamArrayProvider(backupMap.values().toArray());
}

@Test(priority = 140, dataProvider = "devicesInfoProvider", groups = {BACKUP_COMPLETE})
public void verifyInLogBackupJobCompleted(DeviceInfo deviceInfo) throws Exception {
    info("Device id is: " + deviceInfo.getId());
    servicesLog.waitAndVerifyBackupJobCompleted(deviceInfo.getId());
}
```

I want to be able to perform those actions as they appear in the same order but as I said before repeating them 4 times and I did not find any solution in order to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

use loop, for every test separately or for all tests togheter as you wish.

Comment: what do you mean ? to wrap the test cases in a loop? I can't understand...

Comment: I'm not good at Java but something like that: 

for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
  TESTS HERE
}

Comment: Put all test cases in while loop. Like while(x>0){//Your Test Cases. x--;} That's it.

Answer (score 0):

There is [`invocationCount` annotation](https://javadoc.jitpack.io/com/github/cbeust/testng/master/javadoc/org/testng/annotations/Test.html#invocationCount--) which defines how many times particular test case will be executed:

Given you have the following structure:

```
@Test(invocationCount = 10)
public void someTestMethod() {
}
```

the `someTestMethod` will be run 10 times:

[image]

References:

- [TestNG Annotations](https://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#annotations)
- [TestNG Framework](https://docs.experitest.com/display/TE/TestNG)